# ASP.NET Passing parameters to a Javascript function within a masterpage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have this resizing script I got from an answer I found on SO.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeImg(img)
  {
    var resize = 150;
    var origH  = 61;
    var origW  = 250;
    var mouseX = event.x;
    var mouseY = event.y;
    var newH   = origH * (resize / 100);
    var newW   = origW * (resize / 100);

    img.style.height = newH;
    img.style.width  = newW;

    var c = img.parentNode;

    c.scrollLeft = (mouseX * (resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;
    c.scrollTop  = (mouseY * (resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;
  }
</script>
```

It is located in the HEAD placeholder tag in my page.

In the same page, in the content placeholder, I have an `<img>` tag which needs to run the function above 'onclick'.

Therefore, It needs to return 'this' like this:

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" alt="" onclick="resizeImg(this)" />
```

However, this doesn't work. I have no idea how to do this and I tried searching google for some time now but nothing came up.

Comment: Have you checked by placing an alert in the javascript function to check whether is it calling or not?

Comment: The code changes the image's parentNode ( `var c = img.parentNode;` ) In what container is the img placed in?

Comment: @Dev - Yes, I did - it works.
Blachshma - The image is placed in a div.

Comment: @xTCx be careful : your code is not cross-browser : you are using `window.event` which is only accessible from IE...

Comment: Oh! that must be it then since I'm using chrome! Is there an alternative to it that works in chrome?

Comment: No wait... that's not it... Chrome doesn't alert me with 'event was not declared' or anything like that... plus this http://blog.strictly-software.com/2009/10/windowevent-support-cross-browser.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure from where you have copied the source. I suspect `event.x`, `event.y` - shouldn't you be using `clientx` and `clienty` properties. Besides, for cross-browser, you need to manage the event reference and image element can be obtained from event object's target.

Anyway, try out modified code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function resizeImg(e)   {     
        var event = window.event || e;
        var img = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var resize = 150;     
        var origH  = 61;     
        var origW  = 250;     
        var mouseX = event.clientX;     
        var mouseY = event.clientY;     
        var newH   = origH * (resize / 100);     
        var newW   = origW * (resize / 100);      
        img.style.height = newH + 'px';     
        img.style.width  = newW + 'px';      
        var c = img.parentNode;      
        c.scrollLeft = (mouseX * (resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;     
        c.scrollTop  = (mouseY * (resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;   
}

</script>
<div>
<img src="someImage.jpg" alt="" onclick="resizeImg(event)" />
</div>
```

I have created the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4AKU/1/) for the same.

Lastly, consider using productivity library such as jquery which will make things a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. As for using jQuery, I can't. It's for a school project and therefore it's limited, otherwise it'd be too easy :-P I could do it more easily with CSS3 which I'm more familiar with, but then again, I'm limited.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a reference to `this` via the argument list as the context is already there within the function. Change your markup to this:

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" alt="" onclick="resizeImg();" />
```

Then in the javascript function `resizeImg` you can simply use `this` to reference the image clicked on:

```
function resizeImg() {
    var img = this; // will contain a reference to your element
}
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pmBcm/) of doing the same kind of thing with a `DIV` element.

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie I disagree. While I *may* have misunderstood the question, I still provided an **attempted** answer and also a working example of my answer to support this. Which is far more than a simple **comment**.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem really... Thanks for trying though!

Comment: @Paul Aldred : yes it works but with a simplified version which will not have the main functionality here (resizing the image) where stands the problem (`event` is not defined)...